# How to insert text after a certain string in a file with variables

Tags: string, bash, sed, match

I have these variables:

```
file_path="/home/dir/file.xml"
string="<host mac='0A:00:DD:D2:00:02' name='vfp-20vr' ip='10.10.1.122'/>"
```

This is the content of `file.xml`

```
<network>
  <name>br-ext</name>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='br-ext' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:9f:a0:00'/>
  <ip address='10.10.1.11' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A1:EE' name='vsrxa-1' ip='10.10.1.21'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A2:EE' name='vsrxa-2' ip='10.10.1.22'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B1:EE' name='vsrxb-1' ip='10.10.1.23'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B2:EE' name='vsrxb-2' ip='10.10.1.24'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C1:EE' name='vsrxc-1' ip='10.10.1.25'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C2:EE' name='vsrxc-2' ip='10.10.1.26'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D1:EE' name='vsrxd-1' ip='10.10.1.27'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D2:EE' name='vsrxd-2' ip='10.10.1.28'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

I would like to add the `$string` right after the `<dhcp>` flag, something like this:

```
...
<dhcp>
      <host mac='0A:00:DD:D2:00:02' name='vfp-20vr' ip='10.10.1.122'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A1:EE' name='vsrxa-1' ip='10.10.1.21'/>
...
```

I tried using `sed "/\dhcp\/a $string $file_path"` in my bash script with no success...

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not too far:

```sh
sed -i "/<dhcp>/a \ \ \ \ \ \ ${string}" "${file_path}"
```

- `-i` to change input file
- `/<dhcp>/` to select only `dhcp` open tag
- (`\` ) * 6 to indent `string` content

Result:

```xml
<network>
  <name>br-ext</name>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='br-ext' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:9f:a0:00'/>
  <ip address='10.10.1.11' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <host mac='0A:00:DD:D2:00:02' name='vfp-20vr' ip='10.10.1.122'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A1:EE' name='vsrxa-1' ip='10.10.1.21'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A2:EE' name='vsrxa-2' ip='10.10.1.22'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B1:EE' name='vsrxb-1' ip='10.10.1.23'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B2:EE' name='vsrxb-2' ip='10.10.1.24'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C1:EE' name='vsrxc-1' ip='10.10.1.25'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C2:EE' name='vsrxc-2' ip='10.10.1.26'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D1:EE' name='vsrxd-1' ip='10.10.1.27'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D2:EE' name='vsrxd-2' ip='10.10.1.28'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed  "/<dhcp>/{p;s|\( \+\).*|\1  $string|;}" file
<network>
  <name>br-ext</name>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='br-ext' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:9f:a0:00'/>
  <ip address='10.10.1.11' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <host mac='0A:00:DD:D2:00:02' name='vfp-20vr' ip='10.10.1.122'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A1:EE' name='vsrxa-1' ip='10.10.1.21'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A2:EE' name='vsrxa-2' ip='10.10.1.22'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B1:EE' name='vsrxb-1' ip='10.10.1.23'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B2:EE' name='vsrxb-2' ip='10.10.1.24'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C1:EE' name='vsrxc-1' ip='10.10.1.25'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C2:EE' name='vsrxc-2' ip='10.10.1.26'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D1:EE' name='vsrxd-1' ip='10.10.1.27'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D2:EE' name='vsrxd-2' ip='10.10.1.28'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pattern to match the `<dhcp>` part and capture the leading spaces.

Then append the next string, substitute with the full match for the last pattern followed by a newline and the backreference to keep the same indenting.

From that point on, you can extend it with your own indenting.

```
sed "/^\([[:space:]]*\)<dhcp>/{N;s##&\n\1  $string#}" "$file_path"
```

**Explanation**

- `/^\([[:space:]]*\)<dhcp>/` Natch start of string, capture optional spaces and match `<dhcp>`
- `N` Append the next line to the pattern space
- `s` substitute
- `##` The last matched pattern (I have changed the delimiter of the substitute to `#`)
- `&\n\1`   Replace with the full match, newline and a backreference to group 1 containing the indenting and add your own indenting

Output

```
<network>
  <name>br-ext</name>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='br-ext' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:9f:a0:00'/>
  <ip address='10.10.1.11' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <host mac='0A:00:DD:D2:00:02' name='vfp-20vr' ip='10.10.1.122'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A1:EE' name='vsrxa-1' ip='10.10.1.21'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A2:EE' name='vsrxa-2' ip='10.10.1.22'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B1:EE' name='vsrxb-1' ip='10.10.1.23'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B2:EE' name='vsrxb-2' ip='10.10.1.24'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C1:EE' name='vsrxc-1' ip='10.10.1.25'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C2:EE' name='vsrxc-2' ip='10.10.1.26'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D1:EE' name='vsrxd-1' ip='10.10.1.27'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D2:EE' name='vsrxd-2' ip='10.10.1.28'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```sh
#! /bin/bash

file_path="$HOME/test.xml"
content="<host>b</host>"

c=$(echo $content | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
sed "/<\/dhcp>/ s/.*/${c}\n&/" $file_path
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `bash` and `sed`'s `a` (append) command:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*<dhcp>[[:blank:]]*$/a'$'\\\n'"$string" "$file_path"
```

Comment: @Thefourthbird Those leading whitespaces are not significant in an xml document. They are for human readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
strings="      STRING1...\n      STRING2...\n      ...\n" 
match="<dhcp>"  
awk -v m="$match" -v s="$strings" '{ print; if($1 == m) printf s }' input_file

<network>
  <name>br-ext</name>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='br-ext' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:9f:a0:00'/>
  <ip address='10.10.1.11' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      STRING1...
      STRING2...
      ...
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A1:EE' name='vsrxa-1' ip='10.10.1.21'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:A2:EE' name='vsrxa-2' ip='10.10.1.22'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B1:EE' name='vsrxb-1' ip='10.10.1.23'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:B2:EE' name='vsrxb-2' ip='10.10.1.24'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C1:EE' name='vsrxc-1' ip='10.10.1.25'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:C2:EE' name='vsrxc-2' ip='10.10.1.26'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D1:EE' name='vsrxd-1' ip='10.10.1.27'/>
      <host mac='0A:AA:FF:C1:D2:EE' name='vsrxd-2' ip='10.10.1.28'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

Answer (score 0):

For a similar task I use `xmlstarlet`. Obviously you got `$string` from a xml source. Thus you can use `xmlstarlet` to get mac, name and ip values. Let's assume you got them. You can then add a new host into `$file_path` like this:

```
xmlstarlet edit --inplace \
  --insert /network/ip/dhcp/host[1] --type elem --name new_host --value "" \
  --insert //new_host --type attr --name mac  --value $new_host_mac \
  --insert //new_host --type attr --name name --value $new_host_name \
  --insert //new_host --type attr --name ip   --value $new_host_ip \
  --rename //new_host --value host \
  $file_path
```